# Amazon echo dot and firetvstick can be safely turned off by pulling power. Why can't we do same for raspberry pi?

Tags: raspberry-pi, shutdown

Rasperry pi is a single board computer similar to many other like echo dot, firetvstick or google nest etc. I want to enable raspberry pi to get safely turned off on pulling power.

Answer (score 1):

Technically you can. Embedded systems use storage media and filesystems with varying degrees of tolerance to power cuts.  But a RPi running the typical Linux distribution has both vulnerable storage device and filesystem.

The RPi uses a SD card for its storage medium, which are inexpensive devices that could revert to a permanent read-only mode (or worse failure) when power is cut at a crucial moment.  See [Strange SD Card "File Allocation Table" issue](https://superuser.com/questions/1519420/strange-sd-card-file-allocation-table-issue/1519427#1519427).

If the RPI uses its SD card as a read-only device, e.g. its root filesystem is an initramfs, cramfs, squashfs, et cetera, then the chance of  SD card damage might be minimized to an acceptable level.